# Can’t get value of input field in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

For some reason JavaScript does not give me the value option of my input field. It gives me the value of my button however, so something must be wrong with my input.

This is my code
HTML:
`<input type=“number” id=“inputs”`/>
JS:
`Const input = document.getElementById(“inputs”).value`

Comment: `const` not `Const` — keep your browser console open so you can see errors.

Comment: Watch out not to use those stylish quotes (`“` and `”`) too...

Comment: what's the ID of your button?

Comment: Why `const`? Should it be `var` instead? What point are you calling `document.getElementById(“inputs”).value`? Is it on `body onload` event or `button onclick` event? The code provided is not sufficient, please add more like the events you are calling?

Answer (score 0):

Try `console.log(e)` on your return function.

This is easier to do in React, but my solution to this problem has been to look at the object on the next level up.

Hence why you are looking for `e` instead of `e.target` where the latter is your button element.

The solution will probably look something like `e.target.value[0][1]`, as the object returns a nested collection of objects.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to get value of input when it's changed you have to add event listener.

```
<input placeholder="Enter some text" name="name" />
<p id="values"></p>


const input = document.querySelector('input');
const log = document.getElementById('values');

input.addEventListener('input', updateValue);

function updateValue(e) {
  log.textContent = e.target.value;
}
```

ref from [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event)